# firejail opera browser with --private-option

Tags: firejail, opera

I´ve created a portable version of the opera-browser (see  https://gist.github.com/ruario/8416e36372f1a976a713 ).

In order to open it I've got to type the command `opera-developer_27.0.1670.0_amd64/run &` in the respective directory.
This works quite well. But when trying to run it within firejail using the command `firejail opera-developer_27.0.1670.0_amd64/run &` it won't work.

Using the "--noprofile"-option however gives me fine results. So "firejail --noprofile opera-developer_27.0.1670.0_amd64/run &" works alright.

Yet what I really want to do is running it with the "--private" option.
So `firejail --private=[path to a specified working directory] opera-developer_27.0.1670.0_amd64/run &` would be nice. 
Yet I found out that this very command cannot work together with the "--noprofile" option.

Is there a way to start my portable opera-browser within firejail using the --private-option?

System is: Linux/Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

seems like there was some sort of misconception on my part.

When using the “–private”-option firejail seems to have no access to the folder from where I start the opera-browser.
Thinking of it this makes sense as “–private” represents the highest degree of security firejail can produce.

So I did the following:

I created a dedicated folder named “opera-browser” within my “work”-directory (which I already use for firefox etc. together with the “–private”-option).

My new command is:

```
firejail –noprofile –private=/home/rosika/Schreibtisch/work/opera_portable/ opera-developer_49.0.2695.0_amd64/run &
```

This one works as desired. And it has the additional benefit of keeping my add-ons and settings. I´m glad I could solve this problem.

Rosika